# How programmatically create and build an .exe?

Tags: c#, exe, builder

Is there a way to create and build an .exe from C#? (*Editor's Note:* Basically a .NET app that can create and compile other .NET apps - see accepted answer)

I am NOT talking about getting the .exe of my project (which is the only exe building I could find on google), I am talking about generating .exe files from within my program.

How would I create a runnable .exe file from C#? I have no idea how and on google I only find questions on where to find the .exe of the Project, while I want the project to build .exe's itself.

Comment: That is how a .exe is made, by programming, the compiler is a VS build-in, so it created the file for you.

Comment: compiling an exe is a very difficult process to do on your own.  That's why we have Visual Studio to do it for us.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "compiler". Search for "Roslyn", "Emit", "compiler as a service".

Comment: You want to write a compiler ?

Comment: Also, for more information see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495638/whats-in-a-exe-file

Comment: Well your program could write code and compile it to a .exe using a command-line compiler

Comment: "Programmatically" is the word you want. You're asking how to generate an .exe programmatically. And poo on whoever downvoted you, it's a reasonable question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it all up, I was just completely lost..

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah that gives a lot of results, I guess I'm back on the right track again.

Comment: @CodeCaster It appears to me that he made a reasonable effort, but didn't know how to express what he was looking for. He just sounded like somebody who'd been wading through an awful lot of irrelevant google hits. You can ding people for not making an effort (and boy, do I ever), but not for making the *wrong* effort because they missed the obvious. We all miss the obvious sometimes.

Comment: @Ed you are totally right. What you described is exactly what I experienced. (I also had that a while ago, I wanted to read lines and react on that, and couldn't come up with the word 'compiler' ..) Though I understand it that people can't smell whether I didn't do my research or I'm really lost.

Comment: You should clarify from what you want to create the executable? From C# source code? From source code of another language? From compiled but unlinked files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to do it without using external compilers is called [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the relevant class you would use is called [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There there are many tutorials on the internet ([including one in the first link I gave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that will show you how to use it, the topic is too broad to explain in depth here.

Comment: OP says _"I am talking about generating .exe files within my program"_. Using CodeDOM is _a_ way to to that, not _the_ way. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster changed the wording a bit. I agree with you there are other options, for example you could just call out to `csc.exe` and do it with that.